# Bash for loop issue with file name

Tags: bash, for-loop, cp

I have a simple bash for loop and am trying to execute a command inside of it. The loop is so I can execute different file names.

the files are:

```
crystal0_cmin.pdb
crystal1_cmin.pdb
.
. 
.
```

the loop is:

```
for ((i=0;i<=10;i++))
do
cp Files/crystal$i_cmin.pdb Energy/
cp Files/crystal$i_cmin.psf Energy/
done
```

The problem is that I always get the following error message:

```
cp: cannot stat `Files/crystal.pdb': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `Files/crystal.psf': No such file or directory
```

but I never specify the files crystal.pdb and crystal.psf. It just ignores the $i extension for all i. That is, none of the files get copied.

Does anyone know how I can fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is easier to do: `cp Files/crystal{0..10}_cmin.p{db,sf} Energy`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that bash is interpreting `$i_cmin` as a variable.  To fix it, use braces to tell bash that `$i` is a variable and should be interpreted as such:

```
cp Files/crystal${i}_cmin.pdb Energy/
cp Files/crystal${i}_cmin.psf Energy/
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate fix is to use braces as suggested by Adam to limit the parameter name to `i`:

```
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do
    cp Files/crystal${i}_cmin.pdb Energy/
    cp Files/crystal${i}_cmin.psf Energy/
done
```

The next step is to realize that you don't need to use a C-style
for-loop to iterate over generated file names; you can use brace expansion
to iterate over the desired files directly (this is the half-way point
between your loop and William's comment:

```
for f in Files/crystal{0..10}_cmin.p{db,sf}; do
    cp "$f" Energy/
done
```

The last step is to realize you don't need a for-loop at all, because the list
of files generated by the brace expansion can be used as the file list passed
to `cp` directly (William's comment):

```
cp Files/crystal{0..10}_cmin.p{db,sf} Energy/
```